# How to load more images from the API by 10 onclick and limit to 50?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I'm having a hard time understanding how to add the Button with `{handleShowMoreImages}` to App.js instead of Album.js

I'm using an API for fetching Images from this component Album.js

```js
const Album = () => {
  const max = 50;

  // Use State for Images.
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10);
  // API
  const api = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
  // On Mount Call API & Filter Data
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchImages();
  }, [limit, images]);

  // Fetch Data
  const fetchImages = () => {
        // Call the API
        fetch(api)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          // Filter to Even albumId only
          const filterData = data.filter((x) => x.albumId % 2 === 0);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  const handleShowMoreImages = () => {
     // I'm getting an error here

    if(limit <= max) {
      let limit = limit + 10;
      setLimit(limit)
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container spacing={6} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
        {images.slice(0, limit).map((album) => (
          <Grid item key={album.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
            <img className="albumImg" src={album.url} alt={album.title} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
        <Button onClick={handleShowMoreImages} variant="contained">
          Load More
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Album;
```

How can I add the button in App.js and when it's clicked it renders 10 more images until it's 50?

```js
const App = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Album />
      // How to add the button here and render from Album.js
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thanks ahead for your help.

Comment: you want to show first time 10 images, next click 20, and so on up to 50 images then disable the load more button?

Comment: That i figured out how to do, but now I want to move the button functionality to the App.js

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is how to _"lift your state up."_ That is, since you want the button (and its corresponding `click` listener) in a parent component, you need to move that state _into_ that parent. React has a post on this - [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) - that should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final Output:

[image]

```js
const handleShowMoreImages = () => {
   
    if (limit <= max) {
      // let limit = limit + 10; <= you are initializing limit state one more time here,
      
      setLimit(limit+10);
      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------- do this instead
      
    }
  };
```

Full Example:

```
export default function App() {
  const max = 50;

  // Use State for Images.
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10);
  // API
  const api = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
  // On Mount Call API & Filter Data
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchImages();
    console.log(limit);
  }, [limit]);

  // Fetch Data
  const fetchImages = () => {
    // Call the API
    fetch(api)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        // Filter to Even albumId only
        const filterData = data.filter(x => x.albumId % 2 === 0);
        setImages(filterData);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  const handleShowMoreImages = () => {
    // I'm getting an error her
    if (limit <= max) {
      setLimit(limit + 10);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {images.slice(0, limit).map(album => (
        <img className="albumImg" src={album.url} alt={album.title} />
      ))}
      <button
        disabled={limit >= max}
        onClick={handleShowMoreImages}
        variant="contained"
      >
        Load More
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Full working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hdgywj?file=src%2FApp.js)